# How to build a Lotus Domino Database using SVN and Ant, Maven or Gradle

Tags: svn, ant, build-automation, lotus-notes

I'm having a database in Domino Designer, which is under Source-Control.
Now i want to automatically build this database on a build-server.

Does anybody know, how to create an ant-script or maven or gradle, whatever is working, to get a valid database automatically from the build-server or commandline?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found, what i was looking for:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Headless_Designer_Wiki

Thanks Vitor for the Link to Entwicklercamp, it helped me in getting those informations.

This year, Gary Marjoram from IBM had a session on Entwicklercamp telling us about "Headless Designer"

So, my quest is no longer doomed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This presentation by an IBMer given during a user group meeting in late 2012 mentions (page 30) the future possibility of doing command line builds. You might still need the Notes Client installed though.

[Command line build for NSF/NTF](http://www.admincamp.de/konferenz/ent2012.nsf/bc36cf8d512621e0c1256f870073e627/f0155421d5f15504c12577b3005afbd0/%24FILE/T0S2-OpeningSession.pdf)

I've asked about this feature but didn't any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, Marboro, you'll have to be a little more descriptive in your question. If you are saying 'I have a database in Domino Designer which is under Source-Control' then I am assuming that you are talking of the on-disk project possibility of the Domino Designer, and that you are using a Source Control System which is working against that on-disk project.

You will need to go through Notes-specific objects to be able to create a new database (which is what I assume you mean by build a database).

Typically, you would be working on a template on a development server, this template would have a local replica on your local machine, and you do the source control with this local replica. Then, when you want to create a new database, you either do it manually, or you run a lotus notes agent which will do the creating for you.

Comment: Yes, that would be the usual way ;-)  
Yes, I mean the on-disk project possibility of the Domino Designer, but I don't want to use Domino based creation of a database.  
I need to find a way, to build a Notes-DB without Notes... It schould be build on a build-server by something like an Ant-Script so that I can make changes to my Database in Domino Designer, send the source to my SVN and get a NSF- or NTF-file in my artifactory / nexus for building a setup with this DB as a part of it.

Comment: I doubt that this will be possible - there are data structures in there which are just dumped as binary representations. Even IBM doesn't understand it anymore. I fear your quest is doomed, Marboro!