# How automatically import JAR files in Lotus Java Agent?

Tags: java, lotus

I'm developing Java code in Eclipse IDE.
I wrote ANT script for export it in some JAR files.
Now I'd like to import these JAR files in Lotus Agent through ANT script too.
But I don't know how to do it :(

I found this topic, but I don't understand how it can help me
[How to build a Lotus Domino Database using SVN and Ant, Maven or Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989758/how-to-build-a-lotus-domino-database-using-svn-and-ant-maven-or-gradle)

Answer (score 1):

Rombs,

The headless designer command-line you mention in your post will take a **whole** Notes Database which has been stored in a source control system (and this means it has been translated to hundreds of small files instead of being one monolithic file) and then 'compile' it into an nsf. I don't think you can do this for a single agent.

If you want the jar files to be available to a single database, then I am afraid the only way is to do this manually, either into a Java Library or directly into the agent.

Another possibility which could work if you have access is writing the JAR files directly into the 'magic' paths on both your server *and* your notes client.

```
jvm/lib/ext
```

However, there are security issues involved because any code which is in this path is considered absolutely safe and will run without any restrictions. If you have a godd admin, he will definitely not be happy about this and will probably want to have a long look at your code.

If your server is at least 8.5.2 then a cool option would be to deploy your jars as an OSGi bundle (tip from Stephan Wissel, haven't done it myself)